# How can I use special characters in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, special-characters

How can I insert special characters like `♣` and `é` into a sql table?
When I try it I get the error below:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '] ♣ us3rnamé', '123456789',
>   'http://blabla.com/blabla/', 'http://' at line 1

The data type is `text`. I guess that shouldn't matter.

Comment: I don't see how this would help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try addslashes in php documentation

Comment: I tried but it doesn't add slashes in front of ♣

Comment: Ah now I get it. It was no matter of ♣. It was a matter of one '
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to tell the database you want to use a different character set. Try sending a query with `SET NAMES 'utf8'` right after you connect, and before you insert anything.